# Eclipse internal file can not be found in eclipse oxygen

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-oxygen

I am working on Eclipse RCP project which is based on Eclipse 4.4. I can build the project using `Maven Tyco plugin` but I am getting compiler error in Eclipse when Target Platform is `Eclipse Oxygen`. If I change the Target Platform to `Eclipse Mars` there is no Error. I really do not wants to have two separate installation on my computer. I also have 
`Warnings to ignore: Preferences > search "compile" > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings >: search "serialize" > Ignore, "Forbidden Reference" > Ignore` set to ignore Forbidden reference.

I have all the e4 tools installed in Eclipse. Is there something I am missing ? Can someone please help. The file which is missing is

```
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.XMLModelReconciler;
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelReconcilingService;
org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.IModelReconcilingService;
org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.ModelDelta;
org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.ModelReconciler;
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These classes do not exist in Eclipse Oxygen. All these are either in **internal** packages or are marked **@noreference** in the JavaDoc. This means they were never part of the offical API and you should not have been using them. Eclipse reserves the right to remove or change internal classes in any way they want.

Comment: Thank you @greg-449, can you suggest what I should use instead

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what these did or if there is an equivalent.